# Regex - Would Like to Match Patterns Across Multiple Lines and Consolidate the Lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file of program code and would like to use Regex to combine multiple lines.
A typical series of lines might look this:

```
   rp = 10;
   cp = 15;
   wd = 2;
   ht = 1;
   dr = 3;
   ds = 10 + 5 * x;
   sp = 50;
   er = 1;
   Anim(rp, cp, wd, ht, dr, ds, sp, er);
```

All the lines except the last assign values to parameters.
The last line is a call to function Anim() using the parameters.
The file of program code will have multiple instances of blocks of code in this format.

I would like to perform an edit that rewrites the lines that assign values
as one line:

```
   rp = 10; cp = 15; wd = 2; ht = 1; dr = 3; ds = 10 + 5 * x; sp = 50; er = 1;
   Anim(rp, cp, wd, ht, dr, ds, sp, er);
```

What makes this challenging is that sometimes the parameters are assigned in
a different order.  Also, not all the parameters are assigned because they may already
have the correct values.  So sometimes the program code might look like this:

```
   cp = 15;
   rp = 10;
   dr = 3;
   sp = 50;
   er = 1;
   Anim(rp, cp, wd, ht, dr, ds, sp, er);
```

What I can say for sure is that the variables being assigned always have two letters.
And the block of lines to be rewritten always has this pattern:

```
one or more of these:   ^\s*[a-z][a-z]\s*=\s*.*;\r\n   (Note - call this line1 or line2 or ...)

         followed by:   ^\s*Anim(rp, cp, wd, ht, dr, ds, sp, er);\r\n   

and I want to rewrite as:  line; line2; line3;  etc. \r\n     
                           Anim(rp, cp, wd, ht, dr, ds, sp, er);\r\n
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how I can use Regex to perform these edits,
if possible.

I use Notepad++.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\);)\R(?!\w+\()`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\);)        # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't ");" before
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!\w+\()       # negative lookahead make sure we haven't a word and a prenthesis after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Hi Toto,  I appreciate your solution.  And while it does an excellent job of consolidating lines it doesn't meet my requirements for two reasons.
1. The variables on each line must have two letters, such as "rp".  I don't want to include lines like "abc = 1" or "x1 = 2".
2. The lines must be immediately followed by a call to Anim(...)
So this should NOT match:
rp = 1;
sp = 1;
foo(x,y,x);

I believe your solution could be modified to achieve what I want, and I will try to do that.
Thanks so much!

Comment: @CurtisD: Have a try with `^[a-z]{2}\h*=\h*.+;\K\R(?=(?:[a-z]{2}\h*=\h*.+;\R)+Anim\()`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NoKX6j/1). But, may be due to a bug, you have to click several times on `Replace All` button !

Comment: Hi Toto,  I like version #2.  I tried it on your demo page and it worked great.  But it didn't work in npp+.  npp+ has some quirks and I'll try to see what's causing the problem.  But I'm very grateful for your help.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Toto, I learned that \K is not supported in npp+.  I'm not good enough in Regex to figure out another way to do it, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Toto,  One more thing (sorry).  In my file of program code each line begins with one or more whitespace characters.  I visited your demo page and added whitespace at the beginning of each line so they looked like: (sp)(sp)er = 1;(newline)(sp)(sp)er = 1;(newline)(sp)(sp)Anim(...).  Unfortunately, the substitution didn't take place.  I tried to edit your Regex to allow for \h* at the beginning of lines, but that didn't work.

Comment: @CurtisD: You have to add `\h*` at two different places, at the beginning of the regex and just before `[a-z]`.  `^\h*[a-z]{2}\h*=\h*.+;\K\R(?=(?:\h*[a-z]{2}\h*=\h*.+;\R)+Anim\()`   [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GjIxQq/1)

Comment: Hi Toto,  I clicked the checkmark to indicate you have provided a solution.  You have done terrific work!  I could definitely make use of what you have done, but there are several issues.  If you visit this URL you can see the result of my trying your Regex substitution in Notepad++: https://www.mathtutor.com/RegexTest.gif  One thing is that I would like the multiple whitespace characters at the beginning of each line before Anim() to be replaced with just one space.  The second might be a NPP+ problem.  It's odd but the lines above Anim() each have no more than two statements.  Thanks!!

Comment: @CurtisD: for such behaviour, the regex will become too complex. But you can remove unwanted spaces in a second step: Find`;\h{2,}(?=[a-z}{2}\b)` replace: `; `

Comment: Hi Toto,  Thank you for the second Regex.  It works perfectly, and you have been a GREAT help.  I am curious about one thing.  When I use NPP+, after the first step I will end up with lines like this: ht = 1;  sp = 2; (new line) er = 1; ht = 1; (new line).  In other words, there are never more than two statements on a line.  So I tried a different text editor (Edit Pad Lite) and it worked perfectly.  I usually prefer NPP+ so if you can think of a workaround to get the first Regex step to work in NPP+ I would be very grateful.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @CurtisD: As I said in a previous comment, you have to hit multiple times on `Replace All` button

Comment: You're right!  I forgot.  Thank you, Toto, for all you've done!